# Iteration Function Call in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to make an Ajax call for every x seconds, to read the data from xml and use xml data as  variable to call the same function after x seconds

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fetchAjaxContent(msg,time) {

        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php?msg="+msg+"&p="+Math.random(),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('msgs').each(function(){
                    var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                    var ftime = $(this).find('time').text();
                    $("#page-wrap").html(content);

                });
            }           

        });

        msg=msg+1;
        if(msg=4)
        msg=1;
        ftime=parseInt(ftime)*1000;
        fetchAjaxContent(msg,ftime);    
    },time);

}

fetchAjaxContent(1,0);
```

its working on first iteration, 2nd fails.

Functions starts with msg id =1 and time =0 to start the first loop on pageload. in 2nd loop, settimeout to call after x seconds.

What am i doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you define `ftime` in succes function, so that means it's not available outside succes function,

Define `ftime` in main function that should solve your problem.

```
function fetchAjaxContent(msg,time) {
        var ftime;
        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php?msg="+msg+"&p="+Math.random(),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('msgs').each(function(){
                    var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                    ftime = $(this).find('time').text();
                    $("#page-wrap").html(content);

                });
            }           

        });

        msg=msg+1;
        if(msg=4)
        msg=1;
        ftime=parseInt(ftime)*1000;
        fetchAjaxContent(msg,ftime);    
    },time);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

And there is one more problem in your code,

`jQuery.ajax()` performs an **asynchronous** HTTP (Ajax) request. So `ftime` will not set immediately and `fetchAjaxContent` will call continuously with same `ftime`, you should take all code into ajax success function.

```
function fetchAjaxContent(msg,time) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php?msg="+msg+"&p="+Math.random(),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('msgs').each(function(){
                    var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                    var ftime = $(this).find('time').text();
                    $("#page-wrap").html(content);

                    msg=msg+1;
                    if(msg=4)
                      msg=1;
                    ftime=parseInt(ftime)*1000;
                    fetchAjaxContent(msg,ftime);    
                });
            }           

        });
    },time);

}
```

Comment: thank u, it worked but not perfect. Iterations are happening at rapid speed. When i added alert (ftime); to see the value, it is showing NnN. i used parseInt also. XML date is <time>5</time>

Comment: Working Perfectly, Thanks ocanal. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take these codes

```
    msg=msg+1;
    if(msg=4)
    msg=1;
    ftime=parseInt(ftime)*1000;
    alert(ftime);
    fetchAjaxContent(msg,ftime);
```

I found a problem here:

```
if(msg=4) should be if(msg == 4)
```

another problem:

`error` is a function, so It should

```
error: function() {
  alert('Error');
}
```

At whole try following:

```
   function fetchAjaxContent(msg, time) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('msgs').each(function() {
                    var content = $(this).find('content').text();
                    var ftime = $(this).find('time').text();
                    $("#page-wrap").html(content);
                });
                msg = msg + 1;
                if (msg == 4) msg = 1;
                ftime = parseInt(ftime) * 1000;
                alert(ftime);
                fetchAjaxContent(msg, ftime);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }, time);
 }
fetchAjaxContent(1,0);
```

Comment: Sir, replaced that block out side success, still the error persist. Please Look into code, edited

Comment: what could be problem, content need to fetch fr every x seconds

Comment: Problem was with variable declaration, as we moved variable declaration to main it worked,