# how to make data available outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

Please check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9VaW2/1/

I want `jData` be available outside

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '/someurl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var jData = data;
  }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  });
```

But when I do this:

```
$view.availableData = {
                cols:{ID:'ID', Date:'Date'},
                rows:{data:jData},
                options:{}
            };
```

It gives me this error

> ReferenceError: jData is not defined

**EDIT**
update fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9VaW2/3/
```

** I think I found a solution to make a synchronous call `..async : false`. that works. I think the page was loading faster than the data was coming back.... wonder if someone has a better solution  **

Comment: even if you would delete the "var" before jData, so it would be global variable it wouldn't probably set before you want to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define as a global variable.

```
var jData;

$http({method: 'POST', url: '/someurl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      jData = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });

$view.availableData = {
    cols:{ID:'ID', Date:'Date'},
    rows:{data:jData},
    options:{}
};
```

Comment: when I do console.log(jData) ...it gives me undefined

Comment: @Autolycus, your jsFiddle demo is not working actually, can you correct it, or can we see a live example?

Comment: I know...its more complicated than just one function. Anyway I think I found a solution to make a syncronus call ..async : false. that works. I think the page was loading faster than the data was coming back....wonder if someone has a better solution

Comment: @Autolycus, yes there might be a problem about async request as I said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574247/iteration-function-call-in-ajax/10574419#10574419), different frameworks but It seems same problem. take all code into the success function, that should solve your problem.

Comment: that wouldnt solve my issue as its not that easy. :) tried that already by the way

Comment: The global variable won't work properly. There's no guarantee that the callback will execute before the assignment to `$view`. Instead, you should move the assignment into the success callback.